# Issue generating an excel file from a SP with a column datetime using ExcelLibrary c#

Tags: c#, excellibrary

I'm using the ExcelLibrary to export the result from a SP to Excel following Mike Webb's example at: [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

But one of the columns of the SP returns a DateTime field, and every time I generate the excel File that column appears with a different value.

Example:

```
In SP: 08/05/2013  5:27PM
In Excel: 40029.72778
```

Is there any way to fix this? I believe that this is because of the cell format.

Comment: this sounds like a formatting issue.. also when you export it can you change the Column Type or are you needing to do this via the code / Export Library

Comment: I did both in SQL, first a datetime column, and then I tried converting the column to varchar, same result :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show any code but I believe the problem is you need to specify formatting for the `ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet.Cell` object.

The following code demonstrates the problem you're seeing and formats the Cell to correct it:

```
// DateTime = 08/05/2013  5:27PM, from your SP.
var dateTime = new DateTime(2013, 8, 5, 17, 27, 00);

string file = "..\\..\\..\\..\\newdoc1.xls";
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet("First Sheet");

// This reproduces your problem.
worksheet.Cells[0, 0] = new Cell(dateTime);
// This corrects the problem by specifying Cell formatting.
worksheet.Cells[0, 1] = new Cell(dateTime, @"YYYY\-MM\-DD");

workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet);

workbook.Save(file);
```

Documentation for this project is pretty light, but various Cell formatting options are demonstrated on the [project's Google Code home page](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/).